# nodejs registration/login with passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I have a login and user registration form and the username, email, name and password adds to my mongodb and hashes password.  When I logon to my dashboard I get the following error: "NoSaltValueStoredError: Authentication not possible.  I get a NoSaltValueStoredError when logging on with the same username/password I just registered with even though it's in my mongodb.

```
/*  EXPRESS SETUP  */

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const passport = require('passport')

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const expressSession = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
});

var saltRounds = 10; 

//const { username } = await UserDetails.authenticate()('username', 'password');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressSession);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('App listening on port ' + port));

/*  PASSPORT SETUP  */

//const passport = require('passport');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
//const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

/* MONGOOSE SETUP */

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MyDatabase',
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserDetail = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  
  //username: String,
  //email: String,
  //name: String,
  //password: String
  
  username: {type: String, registered:true},
  email: {type: String, registered:true},
  name: {type: String, registered:true},
  password: {type: String, registered:false}
  
});

UserDetail.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const UserDetails = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail, 'userInfo');


/* PASSPORT LOCAL AUTHENTICATION */

passport.use(UserDetails.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(UserDetails.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(UserDetails.deserializeUser());

/* ROUTES */

const connectEnsureLogin = require('connect-ensure-login');

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local',
  (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/login?info=' + info);
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      return res.redirect('/');
    });

  })(req, res, next);
});


app.get('/register',
   /* (req, res) => { res.send('html/register.html') */
 
(req, res) => res.sendFile('html/register.html',
  { root: __dirname })
  
    );

    app.post("/register", (req, res) => { 
      UserDetails.find({"email": req.body.email})
      
      .then(
          async result => {
              console.log(result.length);
              if (result.length !== 0) {
                  res.json({
                      message: 'Email already exists',
                      status: false
                  })
      
              } else {
                      
                        
                      var myData = new UserDetails(req.body);
                      myData._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()   
                      password = myData.password
                      
                      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
                      const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

                      console.log(hashPassword);
                      myData.password = hashPassword;
                       
                      } 
      
                      //UserDetails.register({username:'roy', active: false}, 'roy');
                      myData.save()
      
                  .then(
                          result => {
                             res.json({
                               message: 'User register success',
                                status: true,
                                 send:(myData)
                              })
                          }
                      )
                      .catch(
                          error => {
                              res.json({
                                message: ' User Register faileddddddd',
                                 status: false,
                              })
                          }
                      )
              }
          
          
          
      )
      .catch(
         error => {
              res.json({
                  message: ' User Register fail',
                  status: false,
      
              })
          }
      )
      
      });
      

app.get('/login',
  (req, res) => res.sendFile('html/login.html',
  { root: __dirname })
);

app.get('/',
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(),
  (req, res) => res.sendFile('html/index.html', {root: __dirname})
);

app.get('/private',
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(),
  (req, res) => res.sendFile('html/private.html', {root: __dirname})
);

app.get('/user',
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(),
  (req, res) => res.send({user: req.user})
);

/*
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'),  
(req, res) => {
  var token = authenticate.getToken({_id:req.user._id})
    //res.send(req.user)
    //req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/')
});
*/

//Handling user login
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: "/index",
  failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function (req, res) {
});


app.post('/logout',
(req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/login')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is that there is an issue with the async calls in the `else` block before the save. The block can be rewritten with a guard clause so that the `.save()` will be called after the password hash.

```js
.then(async result => {
    // Add return to create a guard
    if (result.length !== 0) {
        return res.json({
            message: 'Email already exists',
            status: false
        })
    // No longer need the else
                      
    const myData = new UserDetails(req.body);
    myData._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()   
    password = myData.password
  
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    console.log(hashPassword);
    myData.password = hashPassword;
   
    myData.save().then(result => {
        return res.json({
            message: 'User register success',
            status: true,
            send:(myData)
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        return res.json({
            message: ' User Register faileddddddd',
            status: false,
        })
    })
```